# $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that, $A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent.

My approach:

$P(A^c \cap B^c)=P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap B)=P(A \cap B) \times (1-P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) \times (1-P(A)P(B))=P(A)P(B)P(A^c)P(B^c)=0$

Thats not true. However, where are the flaws in my proof?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: $P(A^c \cap B^c)=P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap B)$ How??

Comment: Is it given that $A$ and $B$ are independent? You should probably say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A and B are independent. Denote A', B' be the complement of A and B respectively. Then:

P(A' and B') = P((A or B)') = 1 - P(A or B) = 1 - (P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) - P(A)P(B) = (1 - P(A))(1 - P(B)) = P(A')P(B').

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Just one more question to fully understand everything. In the third step ($1- P(A or B)$), which rule did you use?

Comment: @Kare: I used P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B), but P(A and B) = P(A)P(B) since A and B are independent.

Comment: Thx! The thing I do not understand is, why is P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)?

Comment: OK, I think I got it now. P(A and B) is substracted, because if not, it is counted twice!

Answer (score 1):

Use de  morgan theorem $A'\cap B'=(A\cup B)'$.

So, $P(A'\cap B')=1-P(A\cup B)=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A)P(B)= [1-P(A)][1-P(B)]$. Hence proved.